# Where can you post new Dominion card rule suggestions?

Tags: dominion

**The question**

I am a big Dominion fan and have made some "fan cards".  I have followed [these suggestions on how to make your cards work](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=699.0), have play tested them many times and now would like to share with others some interesting new cards.  Unfortunately there does not seem to be a place to post these.  Do you know?

**BoardGameGeek.com**

This seems to be the place to post, but does anyone else have problems posting to this site?  To post there, the site itself says, you need to confirm by email, but I never receive the confirmation email even though my email address is correct as I am able to use it when I purchase something from the site.

**Donald X himself**

I have recently read that he is working on an expansion coming out in 2015 (yeah!), but I can´t seem to find any contact information either to him or his publisher.

Othe suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do *not* send them to Donald or RGG! There are many reasons, but the biggest one is that most big publishers return unsolicited material *unoped*.

Comment: The new box is supposed to be released on April 18th 2015, according to Rio Grande's web site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have read the post that you link to, then you are familiar with forum.dominionstrategy.com. They have a subforum just for this sort of thing [here](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?board=11.0).  If you post your cards there, people will likely comment on them, give advice, and even try them out and playtest them if they are interesting enough. It's a friendly community with lots of people who are experts at Dominion.

Donald X posts on that forum as well, and you can "contact" him there by asking questions in posts, but he has said that he does not read fan cards, largely because he wants to make sure that any ideas he uses are his own.

Comment: I guess I did not read it carefully enough.  I seem to have problems posting to the forum, but I should be able to find a way - perhaps registering a new user.  Thanks!

Comment: Turns out I managed to post there after all.  Great :)